# Set default value for dropdown in django forms

Tags: django, forms, drop-down-menu

I am unable to set default value for a dropdown while loading forms.

Here is the code

```
state = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices = formfields.State)

State = (
         ('QC_APPROVED','QC_APPROVED'),
         ('REVERT','REVERT'),
         ('FIXED','FIXED'),
        )
```

If I want to make the default state as FIXED. I am writing this code

```
state = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices = formfields.State, default = 'FIXED')
```

If I execute the above code I am getting the below error.

```
Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default'
```

Can some one help on this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
state = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=formfields.State, initial='FIXED')
```

As shown in documentation: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#initial

Comment: Cool its worked. Earlier I am refering to this link http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default

Comment: @Vikram i believe, that you cannot set value as _default_ if it don't exist. You creating model with choice field, there fore choices are created only after .save() method. If choices would be in other class that already exist as model somewhere in db you would be able to use default with it. WARNING I may be wrong! well the main idea is that default could be a model (or part of it) not a value to for e.a. text field.

Comment: great. For anyone who wants to know how to set an `initial` value dynamically, you can use `initial` as an argument when instantiating the form (like in @Nic 's answer below)

Answer (score 7):

I came across this thread while looking for how to set the initial "selected" state of a Django form for a foreign key field, so I just wanted to add that you do this as follows:

**models.py:**

```
class Thread(NamedModel):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=False)
```

**forms.py:**

```
class ThreadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Thread
        fields = ['topic', 'title']
```

**views.py:**

```
def createThread(request, topic_title):
    topic = Topic.getTopic(topic_title)
    threadForm = ThreadForm(initial={'topic': topic.id})
...
```

The key is setting `initial={'topic': topic.id}` which is not well documented in my opinion.

Comment: Pretty cool solution, Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

fields take [**`initial`**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#initial) values

Answer (score 1):

```
state = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=formfields.State, initial='FIXED')

title = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=formfields.State) , initial='FIXED')

toppings = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':"hhhhhhhh"}),
        choices = formfields.State,
        initial='FIXED'
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

If the other solutions dont work for you,Try this:

It turns out that ModelChoiceField has an attribute called empty_label.With empty _label you can enter a default value for the user to see.
Example: In forms.py

```
Class CreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
      category = forms.ModelChoiceField(empty_label="Choose Category")
```

Answer (score -2):

Try the number:

```
state = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices = formfields.State, default = 2 )
```

Comment: Like DTing says above, you should use initial instead of default for forms.  default is for models.